# embed a VF page inside a flow

Tags: attachment, visual-workflow

We have a requirement of exposing e-signature capture and document/image upload functionality in a Visual workflow. Easy Peasy if it was required to be done after the flow. I can embed the flow in a VF and configure the finishLocation as the VF page for e-signature or document upload.

But the requirement is to make this functionality available within a flow. Any ideas? how can we call a VF within a flow?